# Is "I'm glad you were able to make it" often used sarcastically? Ambiguous? Help understanding something that happened to me

Tags: phrases, expressions, american-english, ambiguity

I've lived in the US for 17 years and I thought I had a good grip on the English language, but something interesting happened to me and it has bothered me for a while. I am hoping someone with deeper insight can help me.

I had been organizing an event for a few months, and it was game time. There was a task that needed to be completed around 4 am, and so I built a team of volunteers to help me. The person I had the issue with is American. He had finished an over-night work shift and driven a while to come help. I genuinely felt SO grateful for all of their help.

At one point in the night, I said to him:

"Hey man, I am so glad you were able to make it"

"Why?" he responded

This response caught me by surprise as I expected something like a "You're welcome". Plus, the "why" was pretty darn obvious given how much all the volunteers were doing. So I reiterated my statement, thinking that he misheard me.

"Why?"

"Well, you guys are doing so much and I am extremely grateful for your help"

Then another American guy stepped in on my behalf and said, "I think he really IS glad you were able to make it. And they laughed some. I smiled back, but I was very confused. I mean, obviously I would NEVER want to slight a volunteer and thank them sarcastically.

So my question is: Is "I'm glad you were able to make it" often used sarcastically? Has this flown over my head all of these years?

Comment: Some people are oriented toward sarcastic barbs. I think your thanks was correctly stated.

Comment: Almost(?) anything can be taken the wrong way. If there are no negative signals in the delivery (or prior rancour), anyone taking "Hey man, I am so glad you were able to make it" the wrong way is the one with a problem.

Comment: I am however voting to close this question because it is a matter of communication skills and foibles, and belongs rather on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Comment: It isn't sarcastic, necessarily. It's merely an emphatic explanation. Repetitions in explanations can make people laugh. "He likes red apples, not green ones". Yes, he **does** like red apples.

Answer (score 2):

I have never encountered or heard of that expression used sarcastically in the context you described.

"Glad you were able to make it" can be meant sarcastically as a rebuke to someone who is a very late arrival at an event with a specific starting time.

I am having trouble finding a source to cite for this. [Grammar Girl gives a related example](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-show-sarcasm-in-text), emphasizing that breaking social norms (like being on time) can elicit sarcastic usage with "I'm glad you were watching the clock today":

> Friend: I’m waiting at the front. Movie starts in 5.
>  You: I’m on
> my way now. Should be there in 10.
>  Friend: I’m glad you were
> watching the clock today.
>
> Was the friend being sarcastic or sincere? The later you are, the more
> upset they’ll likely be, and the higher the probability their response
> is a sarcastic jab.

In a more general sense, there is this explanation of sarcastic usage that Grammar Girl cites, from the Journal of Experimental Psychology, ["How to be sarcastic: The echoic reminder theory of verbal irony"](https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2F0096-3445.118.4.374):

> Positive statements, such as "A fine friend you are," can readily be
> used sarcastically. Negative statements, such as "You're a terrible
> friend," can be used sarcastically only under special circumstances.
> We account for this asymmetry in terms of echoic reminder theory,
> which asserts that listeners recognize sarcasm when they perceive that
> a speaker is alluding to some antecedent state of affairs.

Here's an example (not the best source admittedly) of "glad you were able to make it" [being used sarcastically regarding lateness](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11557104/1/Gilderoy-Lockhart-the-backstory), emphasis mine:

> So when he walked into class, late as usual, Professor Harron had a
> sarcastic remark waiting for him.
> "Oh, hello Gilderoy, **glad you were able to make it**. I'm sure you were late because you were showering, right?" 
> "No Professor," Gilderoy responded with his head down, "I didn't have
> a ride to school so I had to walk, sorry."
> "Just go sit down and take out your textbook," Harron chirped at him.

To answer both parts of your question, NO, nothing has flown over your head all these years! I don't know why your friend would react like that. You thanked him properly and sincerely. The response you got was not a reflection of your English language usage!